# laravel 4 function query YEAR(column) get an error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

I am making a simple query request with a where condition. I need to have in this condition the year of a date field, in SQL i use "YEAR(date)=2015"
In laravel when i use it, i get an error because he didnt find the column.

```
$total_num_rows_y = DB::table('insatisfaction')
  ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as total_num_rows_y'))
  ->where('foo', $foo->id_aj)
  ->where('YEAR(date)', '2015')
  ->get();
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try :

```
$total_num_rows_y = DB::table('insatisfaction')
   ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as total_num_rows_y'))
   ->where('foo', $foo->id_aj)
   ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(start)'), '=', date('Y'));
   ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, without the ';' in your script, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use whereYear

```
$total_num_rows_y = DB::table('insatisfaction')
  ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as total_num_rows_y'))
  ->where('foo', $foo->id_aj)
  ->whereYear('date','=',2015)
  ->get();
```